# Compile maven sub-project with gradle

Tags: maven, gradle

i have a gradle project that need the jars generated by a subproject that uses maven.
Can I automatize the compilation of the maven project through gradle and declare it as a dependency ?

Answer (score 0):

A common solution is to call out to Maven via an `Exec` task, then collect the Jar(s) from the file system.

Comment: Thanks, i was wondering if there was a way to have the artifacts automatically "specified" by the task being called.